# How to use JPF or JPEG 200 image formate in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, image-upload, magento2.2.4

I have been given image files in **jpf** or **JPEG 2000** to upload into a Magento 2.2.4 store. But looks like this is not an image file format which is supported.

Is there any way to make this work?

Thank you!!!

Comment: product image format ???

Comment: as for now it is for homepage blocks @MohitPatel